# String manipulation in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a sheet with deposit numbers.  I want to convert it to 13 digits.
1234 indicates the branch code which is 4 digits, 456 indicates digit code which is 3 digits, 1 indicates account number which is 6 digits.
1234.456.34 becomes 1234456000034
1234.456.9843 becomes 1234456009843

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including the code they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: "`1234` ... is 4 digits". OK.  "`456` ... is 3 digits". OK.  "`1` ... is 6 digits." Huh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have a list of values in the form

[Branch Code].[Digit Code].[Account Number]

The values can be numbers of variable length, and you need to pad out numbers less the maximum sizes (4 digits, 3 digits, 6 digits respectively) to their maximum lengths with leading zeroes and remove the period (.) delimiter.

Assuming your list of values is in Column A, my approach would be:

- Use 'Text to Columns' to split the values into their three constituent parts, with period as the delimiter. This will split the values into Columns A-C. 'Text to Columns' is found under the Data section on the Excel ribbon. If you prefer to use functions to identify the constituent parts [this article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Split-text-among-columns-by-using-functions-c2930414-9678-49d7-89bc-1bf66e219ea8) is a good guide to the text functions in Excel.
- In Column D use the following formula to pull the values together, applying the appropriate format to each piece:

=CONCATENATE(TEXT(A1,"0000"),TEXT(B1,"000"),TEXT(C1,"000000"))

Answer (score 1):

If you have your string in A1, this one will convert it to the format you want:

`=MID(A1,1,4) & MID(A1,6,3) & MID("000000",LEN(A1)-8,6) & MID(A1,10,6)`

Comment: I'd have gone with `RIGHT("00000"&MID(A1,10,6),6)` for the last bit if you're sticking with string operators - but the answer from 2015 uses `TEXT(...,"000000")` which is a bit more elegant. Although I agree that using text-to-columns is an unnecessary step. Anyway, welcome to Super User! Good start.